# Why the first EHLO command is "unrecognized command" on gsmtp?

Tags: smtp

I'm learning basics of the networking and want to send a email via command line. I opened a telnet session with gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com:25 and issue the very first command `EHLO gmail.com`

```
220 mx.google.com ESMTP u16-20020ac25190000000b00449fff280afsi9331201lfi.49 - gmtp
EHLO gmail.com
502 5.5.1 Unrecognized command. u16-20020ac25190000000b00449fff280afsi9331201lf.49 - gsmtp
EHLO gmail.com
250-mx.google.com at your service, [xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx]
250-SIZE 157286400
250-8BITMIME
250-STARTTLS
250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES
250-PIPELINING
250-CHUNKING
250 SMTPUTF8
```

When i first issuing `EHLO gmail.com` it says `Unrecognized command` but then it accepts my command. What am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I cannot replicate your problem. `telnet gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com 25` followed by `EHLO localhost` after having received the greeting works fine for me. (You're not supposed to use `gmail.com` in `EHLO`, but this shouldn't matter. The correct way would be to use the fully qualified domain name for your machine (not `localhost`) or your IP address in square brackets if your machine has no DNS address.)

[RFC 5321](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc5321#section-4.3.1) specifies that SMTP clients should wait for the greeting from the server before sending the `EHLO` command. Delaying the greeting can be used as an [anti-spam measure](https://explained-from-first-principles.com/email/#patience), but I don't think that this is the problem here.

Comment: Yeah, the problem was in my putty client. Telnet mode sends hidden escape symbols (i guess), in Raw mode it works just fine